# How to set font for GTK applications on Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, fonts, gtk, evolution

I am trying to use the same font in Kubuntu 14.04 both for native KDE apps and for GTK apps.

If I use the GTK entry on System Preferences to set up the font, I see the following problems:

1: Only some applications actually change the font: For example, it works on Pidgin, but not on FIrefox or Evolution. THis problem with Evolution is my major concern, because the default font is too big

2: THe font size works in a strange way. All fonts look bigger than on KDE Applications and it seems that there is a bottom limit, so I cannot set small sizes

Comment: Are you using Qtcurve?

Answer (score 0):

In your home directory, create these files:

```
.gtkrc-2.0 and .gtkrc
```

In .gtkrc-2.0, insert the following line:

```
gtk-font-name="Fudd 18"
```

In .gtkrc, enter the following:

```
style "default-text" {
 fontset = "-*-arial-medium-r-normal--18-120-*-*-*-*-iso10646-1,\
-*-Nimbus Sans L-medium-r-normal--18-120-*-*-*-*-*-*"
}
class "GtkWidget" style "default-text"
```

Hope this helps.